# RSS feed for BlogSpot

Tags: rss, blogger

Is it possible to get RSS feed for BlogSpot for specific keywords?
I have tried with the below URLs but they do not seem to be working.

```
    Atom 1.0: https://blogname.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default/-/[label]
    RSS 2.0: https://blogname.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default/-/[label]?alt=rss
```

Comment: Please show an example, your second RSS url should work fine.

Comment: @Bassam, will the label be 'specific keywords' here?

Comment: @DushyantJoshi Were you successfully able to fetch keyword-specific feeds using the endpoint `https://www.yourblogname.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?q=KEYWORD`?

Comment: @PrayagVerma yes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For keyword-specific feeds, use the following endpoint

```
https://www.yourblogname.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?q=KEYWORD
https://www.blogger.com/feeds/BLOGID/posts/default?q=KEYWORD
```

The *keyword* will need to be passed as a query string to the **q** query parameter.

Answer (score 3):

Be sure to enable blog feed

Go to **Settings** > **Others** > **Site Feed** > **Allow Blog Feed** then select **Full**

Blogger labels are case sensitive, It will treat **Food** differently from **food**

An example: `https://fordemos.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default/-/Food?alt=rss`

Comment: Thank you. the label will be any term from the blog post content right? because whenever I try with some keywords it is not working. I have already done settings as you mentioned. e.g. `https://dajoshi.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default/-/Magento?alt=rss`